# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.appprofile.accessintent.AccessIntent

Tags: java, websphere, jndi

I'm trying get the data base connection using JNDI Name. I'm sing Websphere application server.
Please find below code.

```
public class GetDbConnection {
        private static Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        Hashtable<String, String> pdEnv = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        pdEnv.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory"); 
        pdEnv.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://10.70.52.228:30305/");
        Connection connection = null;   
    try{    
        Context ctx = new InitialContext(pdEnv);
    System.out.println("Initial Context: "+ctx.getNameInNamespace());

    DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("jdbc/siperian-mdmtrg01-cmx_ors-ds");
    System.out.println("DataSource Object : "+ds.getClass());        
   connection = ds.getConnection();
   System.out.println("Connection established ::" +connection);
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
       return connection;   }
```

I'm getting below error.This is the full print stack trace.

> Initial Context: MDMTRG2Cell01/clusters/InformaticaMDM_Cluster
>   J2CA0036E: An exception occurred while invoking method
>   setDataSourceProperties on
>   com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSManagedConnectionFactoryImpl used by
>   resource jdbc/siperian-mdmtrg01-cmx_ors-ds :
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/ibm/websphere/appprofile/accessintent/AccessIntent

Please help me in this reagrd.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is that the **WebSphere Application Server Java™ virtual machine (JVM) could not find the JDBC JAR file**.

Example if we are using DB2 datasource we need DB2 JAR, in websphere classpath that contains the implementation class.

The most likely cause is that the classpath of the JDBC Provider configuration has used a WebSphere Application Server variable, for example, DB2_JDBC_DRIVER_PATH, which has not been set for the corresponding WebSphere Application Server jvm process.

This could also be caused on Unix based servers by the userID not having permission to access the jar that contains the class.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I have used 3 JARs , j2ee.jar,was_public.jar,com.ibm.ws.exception.jar. Now I'm getting different error saying "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid Oracle URL specified DSRA0010E: SQL State = 99999, Error Code = 17,067".

Comment: Set the field Authentication Alias for XA recovery.